# how to check the a bunch of users is in online/offline and it is online show green dots or else red dot using typescript in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

this is my component.ts code.Really I don't know about that one just I am trying .whether it is correct or wrong however I want to show the if users are in online besides username shows green button or else red dot button

```
 onlineCheck()
      {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            xhr.onload = () => {
                // Set online status
                this.isOnline = true;
                resolve(true);
                console.log("user is in online "+this.isOnline);
            };
            xhr.onerror = () => {
                // Set online status
                this.isOnline = false;
                reject(false);
                console.log("user is in offline "+this.isOnline);

            };
            xhr.open('GET',this.onlineURL(this.appl_name,this.s_name), true);
            console.log("live Url "+this.onlineURL(this.appl_name,this.s_name));
            xhr.send();
        });
```

Comment: you going to check your network status or others? . If others then single user or multiple users? and how you getting status by using http request??

Comment: others like multiple users

Comment: i hope sending http get request to check users online status is not recomented  one. because you can't keep on watch all the users every second. Even you send request frequently also leads to performance issue. You should use real time application concept to achieve your requirement. May be Socketio library will help you.

Comment: how ?please could you give a sample for checking the group of users in online?

Answer (score 1):

This is sample code you can simpleify or customize based on your requirement. 
Many useful features are available in Socketio refer here for further change [here](https://socket.io/docs/).

**Server code:**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
   fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
      function (err, data) {
         if (err) {
             res.writeHead(500);
             return res.end('Error loading index.html');
         }
   res.writeHead(200);
   res.end(data);
   });
 }

 io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.on('myOnlineStatus', function (data) {
     console.log(data);
   });
 });
```

**Client code:**

```
 var socket = io('http://localhost');
 socket.on('myOnlineStatus', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   // Write logic to identify each user and update network status
   // You will get status of each user every 10 seconds
 });
 setInterval(() => { 
           socket.emit('my other event', { myId: 'Raja', status : navigator.onLine });
     }, 10000);
```